# Adjust for loss of follow up

Tags: causality, observational-study

I have a dataset containing 50,000 observations of individuals undergoing drug treatment in Chile from 2015 to 2019. I aim to examine whether polydrug use (intake of more than one substance at the commencement of treatment) impacts the number of crimes an individual is involved in post-treatment (treatment outcomes profile). However, a challenge arises as only 1,730 individuals are interviewed after their treatment, and I suspect potential selection bias in this subgroup.

The post-treatment interview subgroup (Group 2 = 1,730) is not representative of the overall sample, as evidenced by the following disparities:

Fewer completed the treatment (71% vs. 78%).
The median age at admission is younger (34 vs. 35).
There's a higher proportion of females (32% vs. 24%).
Educational background differs, with fewer having a university education (14% vs. 18%) and more having primary education (31% vs. 27%).
Alcohol as the main substance of intake is less prevalent (30% vs. 39%), as is marijuana (4% vs. 6%), while base paste is more prevalent (42% vs. 32%).
Daily consumption is more common (50% vs. 43%).
Employment status varies, with fewer being employed (41% vs. 51%) and more being unemployed (38% vs. 33%).
A higher proportion were admitted with a primary substance (71% vs. 66%) and a secondary substance (41% vs. 34%).
More individuals present with psychiatric comorbidity (49% vs. 43%) and dependence (76% vs. 70%).
Fewer started their drug use with alcohol (53% vs. 62%), but more started with marijuana (32% vs. 27%) and base paste (7% vs. 4%).
The median duration to discontinue treatment is longer (2.9 vs. 2.4).
It's more likely for individuals from this subgroup to have crimes registered with the prosecutor's office (25% vs. 19%).

**Is it possible to do an inverse probability weighting to adjust the characteristics of people interviewed (those who reported) so they can resemble the original sample? Has this approach been used according to the literature?**

Comment: I would expect the bias to be so severe in this study that no correction will make the results solid.